# How do I create an object with custom attributes in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am using PHP and MySQL. My database have two tables: product and product_attr
Each product may have different attributes. Like this:

PRODUCT

```
ID  name
----------
1   Table
2   Car
```

PRODUCT_ATTR

```
ID  productID   attr        value
--------------------------------------
1   1           Color       Black
2   1           Height      35
4   2           Color       Red
5   2           Doors       4
```

I want to create a Product-object with the attributes from the product_attr-table as part of the object. Like this:

```
$product->ID = 1
$product->name =Table
$product->attr->color = Black
$product->attr->height =35

$product->ID =2
$product->name =Car
$product->attr->color =Red
$product->attr->doors =4
```

How do I do that in PHP?

Comment: Are you using PDO or mysql_xxx functions ?

Comment: @sebcap26 does that matter?

Comment: Yes, because the answer will be different ...

Comment: Use an array. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set them using loop or something else, and after that , you can get them, see below:

There are two methods to doing it.

One, you can directly create property dynamically from outside the class.

Simply do:

```
class Foo{
    public function createProperty($attribute, $value){
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->createProperty('attribute', 'value');
```

Or if you wish to create property through your `createProperty` method.

```
  class Foo{

    }

    $foo = new Foo();
    $foo->hello = 'something';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the basics of the [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) technique, in PHP the basics are:

1) Define a Base Class for example `BaseModel` with the following definition

> ```
> <?php 
> class BaseModel
> {
>   public $table_name;
>   protected $db_fields;   
>
>   public function __set($name, $value)
>   {
>       $this->db_fields[$name] = $value;
>   }
>
>   public function __get($name)
>   {
>       if (array_key_exists($name, $this->db_fields)) {
>           return $this->db_fields[$name];
>       }        
> }
> ```

2) Define a class for each entity, for example `Product` that extends the `BaseModel`

> ```
> class Product extends BaseModel
> {
>    public $table_name = 'products';
>    ....
> }
> ```

3) Use the `Product Class` as you want:

> ```
> $product = new Product;
> $product->color = 'Adadsa';
> $product->price = 321312;
> $product->save();
> ```